# can we create angular js application using Simple aspx

Tags: c#, asp.net, angularjs, asp-classic, angularjs-scope

Can we create a Angular Js application in ASPX web forms using three tier architecture (Database Layer,Business Layer)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can in simple Aspx using Web APi or Web Service...

You have to create a new .aspx page (with masterpage if you want) and follow the same approach of a classic Web Form Application (obviously without postback)

include WebAPI for managing the ajax requests or use httphandler with json response format or a WCF service ecc. I don't know your needs...

Comment: But is it Possible without using web API or without adding any web service too??

Comment: Yes, you can use a web service (.asmx) with json response format